# How can I refresh my MySQL dataset from within PowerBI service?

Tags: mysql, powerbi

I have a MySQL database that is running in Azure. Now I have created a report based on that data, by using the desktop version of PowerBi.

In the `Get Data` dialogue, I selected `Database > MySQL database`, gave my credentials and selected the tables required for my report. Afterward, I published my report to app.powerbi.com by using the `Publish` button. So far so good.

The thing is if I try to manually refresh the dataset from within app.powerbi.com it fails. I can't even enable scheduled refresh.

[image]

So long story short: How can I refresh my dataset from within app.powerbi.com?

Comment: Have you updated your credentials in the service? It needs it doing sometimes. Is mysql using the azure service? Or a VM. Have you enabled other azure services to access the mysql instance?

Comment: It's the Azure MySQL DBaaS offering I am using here. Will check the credentials again.